# How to retrieve nested map values

Tags: go

I want to scan AWS DynamoDB table and then pull only a certain value. Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
)

func main() {
    svc := dynamodb.New(session.New(), &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-2")})

    params := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        TableName: aws.String("my_Dynamo_table_name"),
        Limit: aws.Int64(2),
    }

    resp, err := svc.Scan(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

and The output is:

```
{
  Count: 2,
  Items: [{
      update_time: {
        N: "1466495096"
      },
      create_time: {
        N: "1465655549"
      }
    },{
      update_time: {
        N: "1466503947"
      },
      create_time: {
        N: "1466503947"
      }
    }],
  LastEvaluatedKey: {
    Prim_key: {
      S: "1234567890"
    }
  },
  ScannedCount: 2
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve the `update_time` value for all elements in above output. Here are my attempts:

```
for _, value := range resp.Items {
    fmt.Println(value["create_time"]["N"])
}
```

and

```
for _, value := range resp.Items {
    fmt.Println(value.create_time.N)
}
```

and

```
for _, value := range resp.Items {
    fmt.Println(*value.create_time.N)
}
```

All above attempts error out with `/var/tmp/dynamo.go:37: invalid operation:` error.
I am from perl/python background and recently started learning golang.

How to retrieve nested map/array values in this case. Also, any reading references would be of great help. My google search did not reveal anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `resp` above is of the type `*ScanOutput`, which has `Items` type as `[]map[string]*AttributeValue`.

To access `update_time`, you can try:

```
updateTimes := make([]string, 0)

// Items is a slice of map of type map[string]*AttributeValue
for _, m := range resp.Items {
    // m is of type map[string]*AttributeValue
    timeStrPtr := *m["update_time"].N
    updateTimes = append(updateTimes, *timeStrPtr)
}
```

`updateTimes` should now contains all the `"update_time"` values as strings.

More details [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb#ScanOutput).

Comment: I edited your `for` loop a little bit. Thanks for the input. I had run exact similar code in python/ruby and the `resp` was a standard python dictionary/ruby hash. So it was easy to retrieve the values. I thought even in go, the response is a map, and hence I could not get it working. And thanks for the doc link.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`dynamodbattribute`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/) package. it's cheaper, safer, and more readable.

Following your example:

```
type Row struct {
    CreateTime int `dynamodbav:"create_time"`  
    UpdateTime int `dynamodbav:"update_time"` 
}

// ...
rows := make([]*Row, len(resp.Items))
if err := dynamodbattribute.Unmarshal(resp.Items, &rows); err != nil {
    // handle the error    
}

// access the data
for _, row := range rows {
    fmt.Println(row.CreateTime, row.UpdateTime)    
}
```